# Error while using .remove method

Tags: java

I am developing a Client Server Chat Application in java. However while compiling one of the java files i am getting error:

Java File:

```
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class ChatServerThread extends Thread
   { 
   private ChatServer       server    = null;
   private Socket           socket    = null;
   private int              ID        = -1;
   private DataInputStream  streamIn  =  null;
   private DataOutputStream streamOut = null;

   public ChatServerThread(ChatServer _server, Socket _socket)
   {  super();
      server = _server;
      socket = _socket;
      ID     = socket.getPort();
   }
   public void send(String msg)
   {   try
       {  streamOut.writeUTF(msg);
          streamOut.flush();
       }
       catch(IOException ioe)
       {  System.out.println(ID + " ERROR sending: " + ioe.getMessage());
          server.remove(ID);
          stop();
       }
   }
   public int getID()
   {  return ID;
   }
   public void run()
   {  System.out.println("Server Thread " + ID + " running.");
      while (true)
      {  try
         {  server.handle(ID, streamIn.readUTF());
         }
         catch(IOException ioe)
         {  System.out.println(ID + " ERROR reading: " + ioe.getMessage());
            server.remove(ID);
            stop();
         }
      }
   }
   public void open() throws IOException
   {  streamIn = new DataInputStream(new 
                        BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
      streamOut = new DataOutputStream(new
                        BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
   }
   public void close() throws IOException
   {  if (socket != null)    socket.close();
      if (streamIn != null)  streamIn.close();
      if (streamOut != null) streamOut.close();
   }
   }
```

Error while compiling:

```
C:\Assignment_2010HP93506>javac ChatServerThread.java
ChatServerThread.java:25: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method remove(int)
location: class ChatServer
          server.remove(ID);
                ^
ChatServerThread.java:36: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method handle(int,java.lang.String)
location: class ChatServer
         {  server.handle(ID, streamIn.readUTF());
                  ^
ChatServerThread.java:40: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method remove(int)
location: class ChatServer
            server.remove(ID);
                  ^
Note: ChatServerThread.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 errors
```

Comment: Presumably your `ChatServer` class doesn't have a `remove` method with a single `int` parameter. It's hard for us to say anything else, given that you haven't shown us that class...

Comment: It says that `ChatServer` does not have a `remove(int)` method nor a `handle(int, String)` method.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ChatServer` class does not have a `remove(int)` method. Make sure it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Either of the following may be true:

1. Your class ChatServer doesn't have the remove and handle methods
2. Your class ChatServer has methods called remove and handle, but they don't have the exact same parameter types that you are calling them with.
3. You have changed that class but forgotten to compile it; you're only compiling the ChatServerThread class here.